# MYSQL display all records and count related records

Tags: mysql, count

I have 3 tables teacher subject and assignments.  When a teacher logs in, I want to display all the subjects regardless if he is the teacher and regardless if there is related records or not.  If there is no related records (assignments) i want it to display 0.

```
Teacher Table: Teacher_PK, Teacher_name    
Subject Table:  Subject_PK, Teacher_fk, Subject_name, 
Assignments Table: Assignment_PK, Subject_fk, assignment_name
```

Right now i have it like this:

```
"SELECT *, count(a.subject_fk)
        FROM assignment AS b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN subject AS a
        ON a.subject_fk = b.subject_PK
        WHERE a.teacher_fk = $sessionVar
        GROUP BY b.subject_fk
        ORDER BY b.subject_name ASC";
```

The problem with this query is that it does not show all subjects, it only shows the subject if there are related tables.

```
English (3)
Math(2)
```

What i want it to display is

```
English(3)
Math(2)
Gym(0)
Science(0)
```

Thank you for any help.
All subjects in the Subject table

Comment: Showing just the fields from the tables isn't very useful. [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) explains more; please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` for sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  s.*,
  count(a.assignment_pk) as numAssignments
FROM
  Subject s
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Assignments a ON
    s.Subject_pk = a.Subject_fk AND
    a.teacher_fk = $sessionVar
GROUP BY 
  s.*
ORDER BY
  s.subject_name ASC
```

*edit* - moved the filter on teacher id to the outer join section

Comment: not working, it is still only showing two items.  When i remove the where clause it shows all subjects but then it doesn't filter the number of assignments based on the user.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see how that would have been a problem.  I've fixed it now - moved the condition to the proper place within the outer join clause

Comment: BAM! It works perfectly.  What would i do without stackoverflow. You and this blog has saved me hours of self teaching, thank you so much.